# Default document not working after installing SP1 on Windows 2008 R2 x64

Tags: security, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

We have a web site that should only be available for authorized users. So we deny anonymous access for the site. However we do allow anonymous access to the default page and the login page.

When we installed SP1 the behavior of the server changed.  Now if the user is trying to access the root of the site, say http://mysite.com, she is redirected to login page rather than the default page. Is there a hotfix to bring back the previous behavior?

Comment: Have you verified your IIS configuration since installing SP1?

Comment: I am also having this problem exactly as you describe. It's almost like IIS 7.5 (with SP1) is ignoring default documents and treating "/" as a real document that exists. In your case, it seems to be forwarding your site to the login page since the user doesn't have access to view the "/" document.  In any case, did you have any luck in fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

You're default page for root of site is controlled by the "Default Document", which is a list of files tried one after the other when browsing to the root of a site/folder.  Check there to be sure the one you want is at the top, as maybe the SP reset the list or the inheritance of the list.

Comment: There is only one default document in the root folder.

Comment: So you're saying that before SP people would goto default.html page using anonymous auth, but now they are redirected to login.html?  Is this using asp.net forms auth for login?

Comment: Even now people can go to the default document as anonymous. What I am saying is this: before SP1 people would go to default.html if trying to access the root folder. Now they have to specifically type default.html... If they are trying to access / they are redirected to login.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I read in another place that SP1 only breaks default document rediredction on app pools in Classic Mode:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1175925.aspx

I have the same problem and I'm using anonymous authentication and need to run classic mode.

UPDATE: I managed to switch to Integrated mode and this did NOT resolve the problem.